# $.ajax() resulting in parsererror

Tags: jquery, parse-error

I have the below jquery which fetches a JSON object returned by a web service, but I get a parsererror most of the times.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'scripts/php/fetchProbableDrivers.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'tripId' : tripId },
    error: function(e)
    {       

        alert(JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));                                 
            },
    success: function(drivers){
            }
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: post the JSON returned by `fetchProbableDrivers.php`.

Comment: what is inside .php file.? also there is missing }); in ajax call

Comment: If you get it correct sometimes and the error sometimes, the error might be in the data value(tripId) you pass. Check your web service's condition of this value to be. (Eg. might be passing `char` instead of `int`)

Comment: the json you are returning may be the cause of error. are you encoding the json on the php side like `echo json_encode("json");`

Comment: Hey thanks as it turns out all I'm getting in my JSON response is "\n" for some ids but I'm not sure why json_encode() in the php file not taking care if this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is a formatting issue with your json format .
You can check your response by changing data type to "html" and put the alert in success.. some thing like this.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'scripts/php/fetchProbableDrivers.php',
dataType: 'html',
data: {'tripId' : tripId },
error: function(e)
{       

    alert(JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));                                 
        },
success: function(strDrivers){
        alert( strDrivers );
        }
```

Then copy you response and validate your response from the site http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

I hope that using that way you can easily figure out the formatting issue .

Comment: Hey thanks that was an easy way to debug as it turns out all I'm getting in my JSON response is "\n" for some ids but I'm not sure why json_encode() in the php file not taking care if this?

Comment: Honestly, the best answer I came across after hours of searching! I was going nuts trying to figure out what the error could be, but now all I need to do is remove the dataType and examine the output. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the JSON object which is returned by `fetchProbableDrivers.php`
There might be formatting issue with the JSON returned.
Verify the formatting of the returned JSON using http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Hey thanks as it turns out all I'm getting in my JSON response is "\n" for some ids but I'm not sure why json_encode() in the php file not taking care of this?